# Spring Data JPA: Expecting update records in pivot table but insert new items instead

Tags: spring, spring-boot, spring-data-jpa

I'm using Spring Boot and **Spring Data JPA**.
I have a class named `PurchasablePackage` includes these fields:

```
@Column(name = "name")
private String name;

@OneToMany(mappedBy = "purchasablePackage")
private List<PurchasablePackageTag> purchasablePackageTags;
```

and `Tag`:

```
@Column(name = "name")
private String name;

@OneToMany(mappedBy = "tag")
private List<PurchasablePackageTag> packageTags
```

and pivot table of these two named `PurchasablePackageTag`:

```
@Column(name = "display_date")
private Date displayDate;

@ManyToOne
@JoinColumn(name = "fk_tag")
private Tag tag;

@ManyToOne
@JoinColumn(name = "fk_purchasable_package")
private PurchasablePackage purchasablePackage;
```

Actually I have a Many-To-Many relationship between `PurchasablePackage` and `Tag`.

When I want to update PurchasablePackage object I'm getting a list of tags too and I expected the list of tags for that PurchasablePackage object be updated, but this action insert tags list again and make them duplicate.

**What is the correct way to do that without inserting new records?**

EDITED:
Edit method:

```
@Override
public PurchasablePackage edit(PurchasablePackageDto dto) {


PurchasablePackage funded = super.findOne(dto.getId());

PurchasablePackage.setName(dto.getName());

//set purchasablePackageTags for purchasable package
        List<PurchasablePackageTag> purchasablePackageTags = new ArrayList<>();
        List<Tag> tags = tagService.findTagsByIdIn(dto.tagIds);
        tags.forEach(tag -> {
            purchasablePackageTags.add(PurchasablePackageTag.builder()
                    .purchasablePackage(purchasablePackage)
                    .tag(tag)
                    .build());
        });
        purchasablePackage.setPurchasablePackageTags(purchasablePackageTags);


return this.repository.save(PurchasablePackage )
}
```

Comment: How are you updating?
please share code snippet

Also is there any unique constraint on any column?

Comment: I am unclear about your object usage in the flow, 
PurchasablePackage funded = super.findOne(dto.getId());
PurchasablePackage.setName(dto.getName()) 

should be 
PurchasablePackage purchasablePackage= super.findOne(dto.getId());
purchasablePackage.setName(dto.getName())

Answer (score 1):

For save to work, data should be saved in a similar ways as it is retrieved and it should have defined keys (columns)  using which it can determine  whether it is a new row or an old one. Do you have any unique constituent key defined?

Also as per your logic,

you are using super instance of repository to retrieve and  this instance to store,as these are seperate instances, so it might not be the same thing getting updated.

```
PurchasablePackage funded = super.findOne(dto.getId());

this.repository.save(PurchasablePackage )
```